# X-Editable issue with DataTables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables, x-editable

I have an Ajax loaded [Datatable](http://www.datatables.net/) and I would like to use [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html) on its cells. I have already tried the simple way, exatcly like in the example:

```js
$('a.editable').editable({
    type: 'text',
    pk: 1,
    name: 'nome',
    url: 'post.php',
    title: 'Edit name'
});:
```

on a basic link inside `<td>` like:

```html
<a href='#' class='editable'>Name</a>
```

but it doesn't work.
The only way I found to make it work is:

```js
$(document.body).on('click', 'a.editable', function(e){
    $(this).editable('toggle');
});
```

with html:

```html
<a href="javascript:;" class="" data-pk="id1" data-name="nome" data-type="text" data-url="post.php" data-title="Edit name">Name</a>
```

Now it works, but only the first time, then it get the dashed border-bottom and it is no more clickable/editable.

Is there a way to bind events on element inside DataTables cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. Reading carefullly the documentation:

> How to toggle editable. Can be click|dblclick|mouseenter|manual.
>   When set to manual you should manually call show/hide methods of editable.
>   Note: if you call show or toggle inside click handler of some DOM element, you need to apply e.stopPropagation() because containers are being closed on any click on document.

Example:

```
$('.editable').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).editable('toggle');
});
```

But this wasn't enough to fix my problem, I also had to change from using 'toggle' to 'show', but still I can't understand why it is better than the other option. I noticed that with 'toggle' the second click quicly adds and removes the editable popover, but why? If anybody has any idea..